# Updating of NFS-permissions

Tags: linux, networking, ldap, nfs

I have two servers, s1 (debian stretch) and s2 (openSUSE Leap 15.1).

s1 has a local directory with many subdirs which each require a specific group-membership for access. These should now be made available on s2 which I am trying to accomplish using `nfs`. Both machines use pam-ldap (pointing at the same LDAP server) for all user/group management which is generally working fine.

For s1 I added into `/etc/exports`

```
<path_to_dir>  <local_ip_of_s2>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

and then executed

```
exportfs -ra
systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
systemctl restart portmap
```

while on s2

```
mount -t nfs <local_ip_of_s1>:<path_on_s1> <path_on_s2>
```

which appeared to work great.

However, if I update the group-memberships these are not working on s2. For instance:

- I have a directory belonging to group `ABCD` and permissions `drwxrws--x`.
- A local user is not part of this group and can't access the directory on any of the two machines
- I add this user to the group
- On s1, I see that the user is now part of the group and they can access the directory
- On s2, I see that the user is now part of the group but they can not access the directory: `ls: cannot open directory 'ABCD': Permission denied`

The only way I found so far on how to update such a change is by

- Unmounting the share on s2
- Executing `systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server` on s1
- Re-mounting on s2

... which is not really feasible as it is not possible if someone else is currently working on s2 in any of the directories.

Is there anything I can do on either one or both of the machines to update this without having to re-mount?

Comment: after adding user to the group, do you see group membership with `id` command on s2?

Comment: @kofemann Yes, the membership appears using the `id` command, permissions to access the folder are still denied

Comment: Hi @Bowdzone, did you manage to solve this? I've had the same problem and just switched to SSHFS: `sshfs -o allow_other,idmap=user,default_permissions ...` SSHFS does not seem to have this issue.